# CentOS 6 несколько версий php

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

На сервере установлено ПО требующее php5.3. К этому ПО необходимо прикрутить проект Laravel работающий на версии php7.2. Думаю самым простым решением данной проблемы является установка nginx и php7.2-fpm, на котором и будет размещен проект Laravel. На данный момент ПО версии php5.3 развернуто на apache.

Проблема в том, что при установке php7.2 она перетирает php5.3. В ubuntu они как-то рядом ставятся и можно потом их переключать через update-alternatives. С CentOS работаю пару дней. Подскажите кто-нибудь как можно установить две версии php на один сервер CentOS с возможностью переключения

Answer (score 1):

Установить можно. Как вариант скомпилировать вручную в другую папку (например /usr/local) и в конфиге nginx указать туда путь.